# A flood of emotions?

Tags: emotions

What is a word to describe a flood of positive emotions when confronted with a trigger from a past experience?

Comment: I would use the phrase '[wistful](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/wistful)/[nostalgic](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/nostalgic)/[sentimental](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/sentimental) + [euphoria](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/euphoria)/[ecstasy](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/ecstasy?s=t)/[rapture](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/rapture?s=t)' Just pick and choose one word from each category :) I prefer 'sentimental ecstasy' myself. It sounds more mellifluous than the other options

Comment: Can you write an example sentence where the word or phrase would be used? The following is the strict rule of this community. *Questions on choosing an ideal word or phrase must include information on how it will be used in order to be answered*. For help writing a good word or phrase request, see: [About single word requests](http://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info). Please edit your question accordingly.

Comment: When I heard the jet engines over head, I felt a flood of emotions remembering my past.

Answer (score 3):

"A wave of nostalgia"

The madeleine effect?

Inspired by Marcel Proust and the 'petite madeleine' cookie:

> Involuntary memory, a subcomponent of memory that occurs when cues encountered in everyday life evoke recollections of the past without conscious effort.

Reference:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Involuntary_memory

Answer (score 1):

Erm possibly [***a blast from the past***](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/a+blast+from+the+past)?

> a blast from the past
> Someone or something that evokes a sense of nostalgia. *Bumping into my old high school sweetheart in the grocery store was a real blast from the past. Wow, I used to have this baseball card when I was kid. What a blast from the past!*

Reference:
http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/a+blast+from+the+past

A bit more about the origin:
http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/66500.html

Answer (score 1):

There are probably several terms you can borrow from Marcel Proust's [Remembrance of Things Past](http://www.fisheaters.com/proust.html):

> She sent out for one of those short, plump little cakes called
>   'petites madeleines,' which look as though they had been moulded in
>   the fluted scallop of a pilgrim's shell. And soon, mechanically, weary
>   after a dull day with the prospect of a depressing morrow, I raised to
>   my lips a spoonful of the tea in which I had soaked a morsel of the
>   cake. No sooner had the warm liquid, and the crumbs with it, touched
>   my palate, a shudder ran through my whole body, and I stopped, intent
>   upon the extraordinary changes that were taking place. An exquisite
>   pleasure had invaded my senses, but individual, detached, with no
>   suggestion of its origin. And at once the vicissitudes of life had
>   become indifferent to me, its disasters innocuous, its brevity
>   illusory--this new sensation having had on me the effect which love
>   has of filling me with a precious essence; or rather this essence was
>   not in me, it was myself. I had ceased now to feel mediocre,
>   accidental, mortal. Whence could it have come to me, this all-powerful
>   joy? I was conscious that it was connected with the taste of tea and
>   cake, but that it infinitely transcended those savours, could not,
>   indeed, be of the same nature as theirs. Whence did it come? What did
>   it signify? How could I seize upon and define it?